# Expand collpase splitcontainer in win form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, splitcontainer

i am working with split container. my split container has two panel and horizontal orientation. in first panel there are some textboxes and one button. when i click on button then a code run to collapse Panel1 of split container. code is like

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = !splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed; 
 }
```

my problem is when collapse occur then my button and all the textboxes getting invisible. so i next time not being able to make those control visible. so i want trick like button will not be invisible as a result i can click on that button again to make panel1 visible. if possible guide me how to fix or place my button on splitter rather on panel. so guide me how can i do it.

Comment: Isn't it quite obvious that you can't click on a `Button` that is part of a collapsed `SplitContainer.Panel1`? You better store your `Button` in a `ToolBar` or as a `MenuItem` that will be enabled/disabled according to the collapse state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = !splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed;
    button1.Parent = splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed ? splitContainer1.Panel2 : splitContainer1.Panel1;
}
```

Comment: after the second click to do some work and collapsing the panel again, this button vanished and you can't click it again.

Comment: I can't duplicate what you are saying. In my case the button says on the same position while being visible while the rest of the controls disappear. Maybe it's hiding behind another control ? Add button1.BringToFront(); at the end and verify that.

Comment: hiding behind a small unimposing groupbox. damn you, control! :) - nice solution!

Comment: sorry ur tips does not work. this line  button1.Parent = splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed ? splitContainer1.Panel2 : splitContainer1.Panel1; do not work. if possible please instruct me how should i design the form. thanks

Comment: Did you read the comment above ? Maybe you are having the same issue varg had ?

Comment: can u give a sample code what u have said....because things is not getting clear to me the way u try to solve. thanks

Comment: Most likely your button is hiding behind another control when you click the button. button1.BringToFront() will bring it to the front so it will be visible again. So the only thing you have to do is add button1.BringToFront() to the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Related to my previous comment on your entire posting. this is a small solution with a `ToolBarButton`. It will only be enabled if the `SplitContainer.Panel1` is collapsed.

Code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = true;
        toolStripButton1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        splitContainer1.Panel1.Hide();
        toolStripButton1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed)
        {
            toolStripButton1.Enabled = false;
            splitContainer1.Panel1.Show();
        }
    }
```